# ERROR: FOR UPDATE cannot be applied to the nullable side of an outer join

Tags: postgresql, hibernate

I have the below piece of code

```java
Transaction tx = null;
tx = session.beginTransaction();

Query query = session.createQuery("select pr from BatchRun pr left join fetch pr.parentProcesses parent " +
                                  "where pr.company =:company and pr.processType =:type and pr.status =:status " +
                                  "and (parent is null or (parent.processType !=:parent " +
                                   "or (parent.processType =:parent2 and parent.status =:status2)))");

query.setString("company", "COMP");
query.setString("type", "LOAD");
query.setString("status", "FINISHED");
query.setString("parent", "COB");
query.setString("parent2", "COB");
query.setString("status2", "FAILED"));
//lock the records(just for 'pr') on database level
query.setLockMode("pr", LockMode.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE);

List<BatchRun> run = query.list();
```

I am getting the below error while execution in Postgresql.

```
ERROR: FOR UPDATE cannot be applied to the nullable side of an outer join
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.handledNonSpecificException(SQLStateConverter.java:140)
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:128)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2545)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2276)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2271)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:459)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:365)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:196)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1268)
    at org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:102)
```

Please help in avoiding this error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hibernate Postgresql select for update with outer join issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46282087/hibernate-postgresql-select-for-update-with-outer-join-issue)