# How to handle concurrency when updating many to many relations with typeorm nestjs postgres?

Tags: postgresql, concurrency, nestjs, many-to-many, typeorm

I am struggling to handle concurrent requests when updating [many to many relations](https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/docs/many-to-many-relations) using postgres typeorm with nestjs.

I have a collection entity, and it has two *many to many relations*, `content` and `removedContent`.

**The problem**

When I remove content from a collection I want to remove the `content` relation, and add it to the `removedContent` relation.

This works well enough, until I make multiple requests close together.

let's say I make 10 consecutive post requests to remove content. (triggered by quick mouse clicks on a frontend, so that's the "speed" of requests we are talking about):

Desired Functionality: make multiple requests to remove content, each piece of content gets moved from "content" to "removedContent"

Produced functionality: maybe one or two of the pieces of content get correctly moved. The rest are either overwritten by concurrent requests or fail due to `duplicate key value violates unique constraint`

**Implementation**

I have been following the [nestjs typeorm database docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/database#typeorm-transactions) and am:

1. Globally initializing typeorm in app module
2. Using DataSource injection
3. Using queryRunner to create a transaction

*Init module*

```js
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';

@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
      imports: [],
      inject: [ConfigService],
      useFactory: (configService: ConfigService) => {
        return configService.get('database');
      },
    }),
  ],
})
```

*Collection Repository*

```js
import { Injectable } from "@nestjs/common";
import { Collection, Content } from "@orm/entities";
import { DataSource } from "typeorm";

@Injectable()
export class CollectionRepository {
  constructor(private dataSource?: DataSource) {}

  async removeContent(
    collectionId: string,
    content: Content
  ): Promise<Collection> {
    try {
      const removeContentId = content.id;

      const queryRunner = this.dataSource.createQueryRunner();
      await queryRunner.connect();

      let returnCollection: Collection;
      await queryRunner.startTransaction();
      try {
        console.log("contentID start: ", removeContentId);
        const refreshedCollection = await queryRunner.manager.findOne(
          Collection,
          {
            where: { id: collectionId },
            relations: ["content", "removedContent"],
            //lock: { mode: 'pessimistic_write' },
          }
        );
        content = refreshedCollection.content.find(
          (content) => content.id === removeContentId
        );
        refreshedCollection.content = refreshedCollection.content.filter(
          (c) => c.id !== content.id
        );
        refreshedCollection.removedContent.push(content);
        returnCollection = await queryRunner.manager.save(refreshedCollection);

        await queryRunner.commitTransaction();
        console.log("contentID end: ", removeContentId);
      } catch (err) {
        console.log("removeContent query runnner error: ", err.message);
        await queryRunner.rollbackTransaction();
      } finally {
        await queryRunner.release();
        return returnCollection;
      }
    } catch (error) {
      throw new Error(error.message);
    }
  }
}
```

*Collection Entity*

```js
@Entity()
export class Collection {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn("uuid")
  id: string;

  @ManyToMany(() => Content, (content) => content.collections, {
    cascade: true,
    nullable: true,
  })
  @JoinTable()
  content: Content[];

  @ManyToMany(() => Content, (content) => content.removedFromCollections, {
    cascade: true,
    nullable: true,
  })
  @JoinTable()
  removedContent: Content[];
}
```

*Content Entity*

```js
@Entity()
export class Content extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn("uuid")
  id: string;

  @ManyToMany(() => Collection, (collection) => collection.content)
  collections: Collection[];

  @ManyToMany(() => Collection, (collection) => collection.removedContent)
  removedFromCollections: Collection[];
}
```

**Console Output (result)**

From the frontend, I click a "remove button" quickly 10 times to remove 10 pieces of content, which makes a post request that ends up calling the `removeContent` function in the `collectionRepository` shown above.

Of the 10:

- 6 Transactions make it, as can be seen in the `start` and `end` logs below.
- 4 fail due to `duplicate key value violates unique constraint`
- Of the 6 that "succeeded", only 1 contentId successfully made it from the 'content' table to 'removedContent' table. I am guessing this means that they overwrote each other between 'find' and 'save' stages of the transaction.

*console output*

```
contentID start:  881ed9da-9298-4f2a-8fa7-f5034f8d2f68
contentID start:  06da1c39-437f-40a2-9ea3-ead4eaf2c4cf
contentID start:  34d82189-8370-4ce3-8e84-7d62b70667a2
contentID start:  ed6fd783-4171-42a6-be4f-d7ea493e5562
contentID start:  daa8ced6-6fa1-48f0-9293-66d562c0a387
contentID start:  97500f06-16c9-4861-a6a8-789aae2d6e2f
contentID start:  afc03b67-ac68-40ee-ab11-a107e1900545
contentID start:  3ce9caae-2355-43ea-9457-58df4623010f
contentID start:  7d6058e4-559f-4fe2-b8b0-8826a1638790
contentID start:  891cc068-bc27-4405-86ad-b9b45d2c0eb6
contentID end:  ed6fd783-4171-42a6-be4f-d7ea493e5562
contentID end:  881ed9da-9298-4f2a-8fa7-f5034f8d2f68
contentID end:  06da1c39-437f-40a2-9ea3-ead4eaf2c4cf
contentID end:  daa8ced6-6fa1-48f0-9293-66d562c0a387
removeContent query runnner error:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "PK_fd4f7804856c739ee11061e1ce9"
removeContent query runnner error:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "PK_fd4f7804856c739ee11061e1ce9"
contentID end:  7d6058e4-559f-4fe2-b8b0-8826a1638790
removeContent query runnner error:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "PK_fd4f7804856c739ee11061e1ce9"
removeContent query runnner error:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "PK_fd4f7804856c739ee11061e1ce9"
contentID end:  34d82189-8370-4ce3-8e84-7d62b70667a2
```

I have also tried using a `pessimistic_write` lock (which can be seen commented out in the `contentRepository` code above). However it instantly fails with  `FOR UPDATE cannot be applied to the nullable side of an outer join` -- Which this thread seems to indicate locking [many to many relations is impossible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46282087/hibernate-postgresql-select-for-update-with-outer-join-issue). Here's the console output when trying to lock with 4 requests (all 4 immediately fail).

```
contentID start:  afc03b67-ac68-40ee-ab11-a107e1900545
removeContent query runnner error:  FOR UPDATE cannot be applied to the nullable side of an outer join
contentID start:  7d6058e4-559f-4fe2-b8b0-8826a1638790
removeContent query runnner error:  FOR UPDATE cannot be applied to the nullable side of an outer join
contentID start:  3ce9caae-2355-43ea-9457-58df4623010f
contentID start:  891cc068-bc27-4405-86ad-b9b45d2c0eb6
removeContent query runnner error:  FOR UPDATE cannot be applied to the nullable side of an outer join
removeContent query runnner error:  FOR UPDATE cannot be applied to the nullable side of an outer join
```

**Final Ask**

Am I doing anything noticeably problematic? I have only been using typeorm and postgres in production for a few months, so I fully understand I may be doing something inherently wrong.

What are best practices for handling multiple concurrent requests like this? Some sort of queue? Which doesn't seem right given the async nature of nestjs, and especially if I have a fleet of instances of this backend application running...